# Viewflipper onclick not working

Tags: android

Scenario:  I have a view lobby4.xml which has a ViewFlipper and two RelativeLayout within it.
Both relativelayouts have a button called buttonTOG which I want to use to flip from one relativelayout to the other.  Here is the code:

```
    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.lobby4);
  Context context = getApplicationContext();
  final ViewFlipper vf = (ViewFlipper) findViewById( R.id.viewFlipper );
  bTOG=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonTOG);
  final Activity the_a = this;
  final Context static_ctx = this.getApplicationContext();
    bTOG.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(View v) {
          String buttons=bTOG.getText().toString();
          bTOG=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonTOG);
          String mystring = getResources().getString(R.string.Playbyemail);
          if( buttons!=null && buttons.compareTo(mystring)==0){
              vf.showPrevious();  
          }else{
              vf.showNext();  
          }


      }
    });


}
```

When I click the second time on bTOG there is no onClick event.  So I guess I must register onclick?

Answer (score 0):

Should be sufficient:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.lobby4);
final ViewFlipper vf = (ViewFlipper) findViewById( R.id.viewFlipper );
bTOG=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonTOG);
  bTOG.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  public void onClick(View v) {
      if(vf.getDisplayedChild() == 0){
vf.setDisplayedChild(1);
}else{
vf.setDisplayedChild(0)
}


  }
 });


}
```